# ldd with 32-bit binaries on 64-bit system - runs but won't report

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32-bit

My linkers are in

`/lib{32,64}/ld-2.20.so`, with symbolic links at

`/lib32/ld-linux.so.2` and

`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (to the appropriate `ld-2.20.so`s)

When I attempt to execute a 32 bit binary, all is well. They compile fine (I am using a slightly modified gcc `specs` file) and seemingly link fine, and run fine.

When I try `ldd /path/to/example/32bit/binary`, I am told `not a dynamic executable`. My understanding is that this is due to being unable to find a linker to open the executable.

`readelf -l example_binary | grep interpreter` gives `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib32/ld-linux.so.2]`, as expected.

Any ideas why this is happening / how I can fix it?

P.s. - "Install 32-bit compatibility libraries using sudo apt get ... " not helpful, since don't have apt/pacman/etcetera. If I need to reinstall a specific (32-bit) library, then knowing that would be helpful!

P.p.s - The script files installed by `gcc` at `/usr/lib{32,64}/libc.so` group the appropriate (real) `libc.so.6` and `libc_nonshared.a` files, with the `AS_NEEDED ( /lib32/ld-linux.so.2 ) )` at the tail end for lib32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is pretty easy.

`/usr/bin/ldd` is just a script file.

Opening the script file shows a line near the top, which initially reads (on my system):

`RTLDLIST="/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2"`.

Changing this line to 
`RTLDLIST="/lib32/ld-linux.so.2 /lib64/..."` immediately fixed the problem.

P.s. (adding here in case it helps someone else struggling to install gobject-introspection) The solution is also useful if trying to install gobject-introspection, because that calls `ldd` to resolve libraries.

The error message I got there was : `ERROR: can't resolve libraries to shared libraries: gobject-2.0, glib-2.0`